# Is there a way to catch ctrl-c and ask the user to confirm?

Tags: powershell, copy-paste

Powershell scripts can easily be terminated by the user pressing ctrl-c. Is there a way for a Powershell script to catch ctrl-c and ask the user to confirm whether he really wanted to terminate the script?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do the opposite. Powershell ALWAYS asks me to confirm termination.

Comment: How did you get it to do that?

Comment: It's just how it was when I installed Windows 7; it drives me crazy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [this post on the MSDN forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/fb409048-a607-4895-8ab3-08c2ec656c7a).

```
[console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true
while ($true)
{
    write-host "Processing..."
    if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
    {
        $key = [system.console]::readkey($true)
        if (($key.modifiers -band [consolemodifiers]"control") -and ($key.key -eq "C"))
        {
            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
            if ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit Script?", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo) -eq "Yes")
            {
                "Terminating..."
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use a GUI MessageBox for the confirmation, you can use Read-Host instead, or $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() as David showed in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
while ($true)
{
    Write-Host "Do this, do that..."

    if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and (3 -eq [int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("AllowCtrlC,IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character))
    {
            Write-Host "You pressed CTRL-C. Do you want to continue doing this and that?" 
            $key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown")
            if ($key.Character -eq "N") { break; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it not interfere with other code that uses $host.ui.rawui.readkey()?