# Press hotkey to rerun script during a loop but don't wait for it

Tags: loops, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

Basically I have a script that runs and it Start-Sleep for 30 minutes then loops around again and re-runs. I was wondering if there was a way where you could click on the window, press a hotkey, and have it just refresh manually?

```
 while($true){
    $data = @("device1", "device2")

    ForEach ($server in $data) {

    ping $server

start-sleep 1800
clear
     }
    }
```

Comment: I do not because I have no idea how that would even be initiated, unless you mean my script that loops, then i added a small example of how that loops.

Comment: so I see nothing wrong with this script, what is that you are missing?

Comment: Well, my question on this thread is if there is a way to press a hotkey to rerun it when it is in a start-sleep status.

Comment: ok, now I finally understand what you are talking, so "break" the sleep with a hotkey, right and go through the loop again?

Comment: Script sleeps for 30min after it runs, would like to be able to press a hotkey and then it will break and restart the script. Just in case you dont want to wait 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found through other methods that the below has allowed me to check the screen for any key press and break if there is one, but still be in a start-sleep status.

```
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30

$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout){

        if ($host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable) {

            $key = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() 

            break 

            }

start-sleep -seconds 5          

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess, your best bet is to implement a `for` loop inside your main while loop that does check for key press once every 5-15 seconds and if it detects that, it breaks itself, so your while loop can start over, here are a few links that seem to be relevant:

[Waiting for user input with a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150161/waiting-for-user-input-with-a-timeout)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2014/01/29/read-host-with-a-timeout-kind-of/
[How to stop while($true) that contains start-sleep in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545166/how-to-stop-whiletrue-that-contains-start-sleep-in-powershell)
[Is there a way to catch ctrl-c and ask the user to confirm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733718/is-there-a-way-to-catch-ctrl-c-and-ask-the-user-to-confirm)