# Downloading large files in Windows command prompt / PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line, webclient, microsoft-bits

I'm kind of running out of options now...

**Attempt 1**

Use iwr in Powershell. It works, shows progress but its 10X slower and doesn't flush until while file is in memory :(.

```
 powershell -command "& { iwr https://github.com/mitchellspryn/AirsimHighPolySuv/releases/download/V1.0.0/SUV.zip -OutFile SUV.zip }"
```

**Attempt 2**

Use .Net webclient in Powershell. It works but shows no progress and you can't terminate by Ctrl+C :(. Last issue is a big setback.

```
powershell -command "& { (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://github.com/mitchellspryn/AirsimHighPolySuv/releases/download/V1.0.0/SUV.zip', 'SUV.zip') }"
```

**Attempt 3**

Use BITS transfer in Powershell. It works, shows progress and almost perfect... until you find out that it [mysteriously doesn't work on GitHub](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/bits-transfer-with-github/) (errors out with 403 forbidden)!!

```
powershell -command "& { Start-BitsTransfer -Source https://github.com/mitchellspryn/AirsimHighPolySuv/releases/download/V1.0.0/SUV.zip -Destination SUV.zip }"
```

Comment: Why run `powershell.exe` separately (`powershell.exe -command ...`)? Just run the command you need directly from the PowerShell command line.

Comment: I'm using this from another build script and converting whole script to PS is not our goal for now.

Comment: I tried `Start-BitsTransfer` on a github asset today, and it worked. (even tried yours). Is it possible this now works on Github like ou wanted?

Answer (score 10):

After some research I found [@MichaelS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510480/michaels)'s method the simplest, nevertheless I added some modifications that you could find useful, as such:

1. Added `Try`/`Finally` blocks, so we could handle user interruptions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and cleanup (See [Gracefully stopping in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710698/gracefully-stopping-in-powershell))
2. Utilize `Write-Progress` functionality, so it feels more like `Start-BitsTransfer`
3. Buffer size optimization, atleast for my particular connection/machine (see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2004/12/tr-2004-136.pdf, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034155/10504393)

In action it looks like on [that gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivyM3.gif).

```bsh
function Get-FileFromURL {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [System.Uri]$URL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Filename
    )

    process {
        try {
            $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($URL)
            $request.set_Timeout(5000) # 5 second timeout
            $response = $request.GetResponse()
            $total_bytes = $response.ContentLength
            $response_stream = $response.GetResponseStream()

            try {
                # 256KB works better on my machine for 1GB and 10GB files
                # See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2004/12/tr-2004-136.pdf
                # Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034155/10504393
                $buffer = New-Object -TypeName byte[] -ArgumentList 256KB
                $target_stream = [System.IO.File]::Create($Filename)

                $timer = New-Object -TypeName timers.timer
                $timer.Interval = 1000 # Update progress every second
                $timer_event = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
                    $Global:update_progress = $true
                }
                $timer.Start()

                do {
                    $count = $response_stream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
                    $target_stream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
                    $downloaded_bytes = $downloaded_bytes + $count

                    if ($Global:update_progress) {
                        $percent = $downloaded_bytes / $total_bytes
                        $status = @{
                            completed  = "{0,6:p2} Completed" -f $percent
                            downloaded = "{0:n0} MB of {1:n0} MB" -f ($downloaded_bytes / 1MB), ($total_bytes / 1MB)
                            speed      = "{0,7:n0} KB/s" -f (($downloaded_bytes - $prev_downloaded_bytes) / 1KB)
                            eta        = "eta {0:hh\:mm\:ss}" -f (New-TimeSpan -Seconds (($total_bytes - $downloaded_bytes) / ($downloaded_bytes - $prev_downloaded_bytes)))
                        }
                        $progress_args = @{
                            Activity        = "Downloading $URL"
                            Status          = "$($status.completed) ($($status.downloaded)) $($status.speed) $($status.eta)"
                            PercentComplete = $percent * 100
                        }
                        Write-Progress @progress_args

                        $prev_downloaded_bytes = $downloaded_bytes
                        $Global:update_progress = $false
                    }
                } while ($count -gt 0)
            }
            finally {
                if ($timer) { $timer.Stop() }
                if ($timer_event) { Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $timer_event.Id }
                if ($target_stream) { $target_stream.Dispose() }
                # If file exists and $count is not zero or $null, than script was interrupted by user
                if ((Test-Path $Filename) -and $count) { Remove-Item -Path $Filename }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if ($response) { $response.Dispose() }
            if ($response_stream) { $response_stream.Dispose() }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where I've got this piece of code from originally but I've modified it several times. Hope this will help you.

```
function downloadFile($url, $targetFile)
{
    "Downloading $url"
    $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"
    $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $request.set_Timeout(15000) #15 second timeout
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024)
    $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create
    $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB
    $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
    $downloadedBytes = $count
    while ($count -gt 0)
    {
        [System.Console]::CursorLeft = 0
        [System.Console]::Write("Downloaded {0}K of {1}K", [System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024), $totalLength)
        $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
        $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
        $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count
    }
    "Finished Download"
    $targetStream.Flush()
    $targetStream.Close()
    $targetStream.Dispose()
    $responseStream.Dispose()
}

downloadFile "http://URL_to_your_file" "C:\Path\to\destination.file"
```

Comment: Can user cancel this by Ctrl+C?