# How to fill in URL & Filename parameters in this specific example

Tags: powershell, parameters

I need to simply specify the `$URL` & `$Filename`  (source destination basically) but do not know the syntax and assume this is where I would enter it:

```
function Get-FileFromURL {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [System.Uri]$URL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Filename
    )
```

Reference Source of above code:

> [Downloading large files in Windows command prompt / PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830703/downloading-large-files-in-windows-command-prompt-powershell)

*Kobalt's comment.

Do I need to simply set `$URL` & `$Filename` prior to the function?

Comment: Are just you trying to call that function?

Comment: I need to enter a URL and a filename.  The URL is the source of a file. The filename is the destination output of the downloaded URL file.

Comment: I recognize this now. The $URL and $Filename must be specified before the function begins.  I will set this information first.  May be a confusing question because it is entry level Powershell.  And yes @zdan , the function is called if a situation exists.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to call a function ([with a formal param block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-6)) in PowerShell and provide parameter values.

Positional (space-delimited and parameters are matched based on Position):

```
Get-FileFromURL http://someurlstring somepathstring
```

Named (order doesn't matter, the parameter name is the variable name in the param definition):

```
Get-FileFromURL -URL http://someurlstring -Filename somepathstring
```

Either of these will invoke the `Get-FileFromURL` with the values you provide.

The URL parameter is expecting a `Uri` object type, but PowerShell/.Net will convert a string for you as long as it meets the [URI format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Uri__ctor_System_String_).