# Exit PowerShell script in controlled fashion using keyboard shortcut

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that performs numerous file management tasks and occasionally I have the need to terminate the script before it has finished processing.  In order to terminate the script cleanly and not leave any files dotted around, I have the script read in a variable from a config file every time the foreach of the gci results is processed, as below:

```
Get-ChildItem $fileDir -Filter *.doc | Foreach-Object {
    Get-Content $confFile | Foreach-Object {
        $var = $_.Split('=')
        New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1] -Force
    }
    if ($process -eq "TRUE") {
        <process File operations>
    }
}
```

This allows me to change the value of `process` in the config file to anything but TRUE and the script will skip the process (although still loop though until complete).

Is there anyway to use a keyboard shortcut to exit the script in a controlled fashion? i.e. after an iteration of the foreach loop has completed.  e.g. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and it will exit cleanly as opposed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gracefully stopping in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710698/gracefully-stopping-in-powershell)

Comment: _occasionally I have the need to terminate the script before it has finished_ this is in fact a design problem.